# Django test db schema missing columns present in live db

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I'm trying to set up more robust testing for my Django project but upon running `python manage.py test` I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.InFailedSqlTransaction: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
```

Presumably caused by:

```
postgres_1  | 2020-08-21 16:15:11.365 UTC [441] STATEMENT:  CREATE DATABASE "test_postgres" 
postgres_1  | 2020-08-21 16:15:16.594 UTC [443] ERROR:  column memberships_membership.level does not exist at character 151
postgres_1  | 2020-08-21 16:15:16.594 UTC [443] STATEMENT:  SELECT "memberships_membership"."id", "memberships_membership"."created_at", "memberships_membership"."modified_at", "memberships_membership"."name", "memberships_membership"."level", "memberships_membership"."stripe_id", "memberships_membership"."active", "memberships_membership"."info", "memberships_membership"."amount", "memberships_membership"."interval", "memberships_membership"."interval_count", "memberships_membership"."currency", "memberships_membership"."desktop_access", "memberships_membership"."past_projects" FROM "memberships_membership" WHERE ("memberships_membership"."active" = true AND "memberships_membership"."info" = 'Default free plan that allows TradePros to view Jobs/Leads but not interact with them or any TradeUser.' AND "memberships_membership"."level" = 1 AND "memberships_membership"."name" = 'Trades')
postgres_1  | 2020-08-21 16:15:16.595 UTC [443] ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
```

This is odd because the column is certainly present in the admin dashboard and even upon inspecting the database, we observe that the `level` column is there:

```
postgres=# \d memberships_membership
                                         Table "public.memberships_membership"
     Column     |           Type           | Collation | Nullable |                      Default                     
  
----------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+--------------------------------------------------
--
 id             | integer                  |           | not null | nextval('memberships_membership_id_seq'::regclass
)
 created_at     | timestamp with time zone |           | not null | 
 modified_at    | timestamp with time zone |           | not null | 
 name           | character varying(100)   |           | not null | 
 active         | boolean                  |           | not null | 
 info           | character varying(255)   |           | not null | 
 amount         | integer                  |           | not null | 
 currency       | character varying(5)     |           | not null | 
 interval       | character varying(10)    |           | not null | 
 stripe_id      | character varying(80)    |           |          | 
 desktop_access | boolean                  |           | not null | 
 past_projects  | boolean                  |           | not null | 
 interval_count | integer                  |           | not null | 
 level          | integer                  |           | not null |
```

However, after reading the Django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/testing/overview/#the-test-database) and other stackoverflow posts, it seems like the test database schema should be the same as live and automatically include all of the migrations that have been applied to the project.  I have tried to reset migrations and re-apply to no luck.

How can I ensure that the schema of the automatically created test database is synced with the live working database?

Comment: Is your migrations in sync with your model?

You can try to run `./manage.py makemigrations --dry-run` to check.

If it's ok, you will see `No changes detected`. If not, you have to make a new migration and apply it.

Comment: Yes I have tried to `makemigrations` but get `No changes detected`.  Also, all migrations are applied when running `python manage.py showmigrations`

Answer (score 1):

After banging my head against this wall for a while, I realized the issue was linked to a default foreign key of a model being set to a  function that returns a default object or creates it if it doesn't yet exist:

```
membership = models.ForeignKey(Membership, default=get_default_membership, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT)
```

The function in question:

```
def get_default_membership():
    try:
        obj, created = Membership.objects.get_or_create(
            name='Trades',
            active=True,
            info='Sample info'
        )
        return obj.pk
    except:
        pass
```

Because the Membership model had been modified (adding the level field) after this function was set as a default for the foreign key, migrations were performed out of order when setting up a fresh test DB.

The solution was to add a dependency upon the specific migration when the level field was added.  This dependency should be added to the specific migration file where `default=get_default_membership` was introduced:

```
    dependencies = [
        ('memberships', '0014_auto_20200804_2358')
    ]
```